# PCI DSS or PCI Standard - Standards | Requirement | Implementation

Tags: pci-dss, compliance, iso27001, standards

I have done ISO 27001 implementation and auditin. I want to get a clear idea of PCIDSS standard.

- What is PCI DSS (I know the abbreviation)
- What are all the materials and sites to refer?
- What are all the standard documents to refer?
- What are the professional certifications that can be achieved through PCI DSS for an individual?

Kindly help me with those points.

Comment: All your answers on one site: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/

Comment: Welcome to Security.StackExchange. We expect that before you ask a question you do some research on your own and/or telling us what research you have done. That way, we don't end up telling you what you already know, or we don't become your replacement for Google or a Wikipedia search.

Comment: @schroeder thank u for the info! I wanted to move in a real-time manner by interacting with someone who has got hands on experience in implementing the thing!

Comment: @schroeder I agree with that point. I myself is a LA in ISO27k :-) I know little about PCI DSS. I just wanna get deeper and know the skeleton.

Comment: It's all on their site.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the PCI DSS Standard [here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/document_library). This is the official site and the only one you should be referring to.

https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

Their certification program for individuals can be found [here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/program_training_and_qualification/)